# Delphi 11 app in Android Play Store shows warning: Non-SDK API

Tags: android, delphi, google-play, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

The "Pre-launch report overview" in "Google Play Console" shows this warning:

Type:

```
Non-SDK API
```

API:

```
Landroid/view/MotionEvent;-><init>()V
```

Stack trace:

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/MotionEvent;-><init>()V
```

This error has previously been fixed in Delphi 10.3, see https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22046
but its now back in Delphi 11?

The solutions I can find on Google is about setting a newer `targetSdkVersion` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`
However, we already set it to API level 30, as it is required to deploy to the new Play Store. In AndroidManifest.xml we have:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
```

Anyone having seen this error lately with a "Delphi 11" app on Play Store? - and eventually having found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

What happened here is that the root of the problem (i.e. referencing the parameter-less constructor for `android.view.MotionEvent`) has not been really solved but rather workaround-ed by making the default target API level = `28` on Delphi 10.3.1. With this the warning dialog no longer shows on screen but you can still see the non-SDK warning by using the `Monitor` tool with your device set up for USB debugging.